# Is there a point in cascade encryption?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, disk-encryption

I was reading the other day about some programs (ex: DiskCryptor), and with my limited knowledge of cryptography.. I started wondering about cascading encryptions (ex: AES-Twofish-Blowfish).

Assuming you use a fairly random password, is there that much difference between using cascading encryption and just using AES?

Comment: what does the password affect the decision?